# Twitter > AFnetworking > Custom Cell

Tags: iphone, ios, json, twitter, afnetworking

I am using `SEMasonryView` to get a pinterest style view in my iOS app but I can't seem to connect the JSON to each individual boxes. Everytime I run the code it just returns

> ***"2013-06-06 15:48:35.160 MasonryViewDemo[7366:c07] width: 320.000000"*** in the console.

Here is what I am doing in the MainViewController:

```
- (void)fetchData {
    // set your MasonryView to be in loading state
    self.masonryView.loading = YES;
    // disable the reload button
    reloadButton.enabled = NO;

    // load data from Flickr's API. In this case, a search with the keyword "Lego" is made and 10 results are returned in each page.
    // The call uses AFNetworking Library, can be grabbed for free from https://github.com/AFNetworking/AFNetworking
    // Of course, you can use any networking library or Apple's default libraries for this task

    NSString *urlString = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"http://search.twitter.com/search.json?q=from:marcofolio"];
    NSURLRequest *request = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:urlString]];
    SEJSONRequestOperation *operation = [SEJSONRequestOperation JSONRequestOperationWithRequest:request success:^(NSURLRequest *request, NSHTTPURLResponse *response, id JSON) {
        for (NSDictionary *photo in [[JSON dictionaryForKey:@"photos"] arrayForKey:@"text"]) {
            // add each of the photo object to your array, so that you can reference them on other methods
            [self.photos addObject:photo];

            // create a cell for each photo and add it to your MasonryView
            SEMasonryCell *cell;
            if (self.masonryView.horizontalModeEnabled) {
                cell = [[[NSBundle mainBundle] loadNibNamed:@"HorizontalCell" owner:self options:nil] objectAtIndex: 0];
                cell.horizontalModeEnabled = YES;
                // randomize image widths (for demonstration purposes only)
                cell.imageWidth = 150 + arc4random() % 150;
            } else {
                cell = [[[NSBundle mainBundle] loadNibNamed:@"VerticalCell" owner:self options:nil] objectAtIndex: 0];
                cell.horizontalModeEnabled = NO;

                // randomize image heights (for demonstration purposes only)
                cell.imageHeight = 50 + arc4random() % 150;
            }

            // set a tag for your cell, so that you can refer to it when there are interactions like tapping etc..
            cell.tag = [self.photos indexOfObject:photo];

            // set the cell's size, if you want to play with cell spacings and stuff, this is the place
            if (screenWidth % 256 == 0) { // for iPad
                if (self.masonryView.horizontalModeEnabled)
                    [cell setFrame:CGRectMake(10, 10, cell.frame.size.width + 15, 216)];
                else
                    [cell setFrame:CGRectMake(10, 10, 236, cell.frame.size.height + 15)];
            } else { // for iPhone
                [cell setFrame:CGRectMake(10, 10, 140, cell.frame.size.height + 15)];
            }

            // finally, update the cell's controls with the data coming from the API
            [cell updateCellInfo:photo];

            // add it to your MasonryView
            [masonryView addCell:cell];
        }
        // you are done loading, so turn off MasonryView's loading state
        self.masonryView.loading = NO;
        reloadButton.enabled = YES;
    }                                     
    failure:^(NSURLRequest *request, NSHTTPURLResponse *response, NSError *error) {
        NSLog(@"error");
        // if there has been an error, again turn of MasonryView's loading state
        self.masonryView.loading = NO;
        reloadButton.enabled = YES;
    }];
    [operation start];

    // increase the counter so that the next time this method loads, it is gonna load the next page
    pageCounter++;
}
```

**And in the custom cell:**

```
- (void)updateCellInfo:(NSDictionary *)data {
    self.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@ %@ %@", [data stringForKey:@"text"], [data   stringForKey:@"text"], [data stringForKey:@"text"]];
    [super updateCellInfo:data];
}
```

Comment: Have you tried logging the JSON returned?

Comment: And why you post two same questions? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16971053/json-twitter-ios

Comment: Oh sorry i will take it out

Comment: I will try it in the morning and get back to you.  @verbumdei